# How do I ignore the header column and row in a csv file imported into python?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, matrix, a-star

I imported a csv file into python using Pandas, I am using the given matrix in csv to preform an astar algorithm. 
The problem is when I import the csv file it has a header column and row with 1...173 and the row of 1 1.1...1.123 
and the columns and rows are continuing 
my code is only looking for 0s and 1s and these numbers are messing it up i believe

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gB0rfaWK2sr3doNxeMFJvjbPcFh8nTFc/view?usp=sharing 
In the photo you will be able to tell what I am referring to
I need to ignore these lines, deleting the first row doesnt delete that row rather the row next to it

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\605760\Desktop\path rec\matrix.csv')
```

and when its referring to the neighbors

```
  for i, j in neighbors:
            neighbor = current[0] + i, current[1] + j
            tentative_g_score = gscore[current] + heuristic(current, neighbor)
            if 0 <= neighbor[0] < array.shape[0]:
                if 0 <= neighbor[1] < array.shape[1]:                
                    if array[neighbor[0]][neighbor[1]] == 1:
                        continue
```

Comment: ```header=None``` and ```index=False``` didn't work?

Comment: `pd.read_csv(path, skiprows=...)`?

Comment: `skiprows=1` is also an option

Answer (score 0):

use skiprows=1

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\605760\Desktop\path rec\matrix.csv',skiprows=1)
```

Comment: it just removes the first row of all 1s, not the actual headers with the numbers 1 1.1.1.2 etc

Comment: @AricaChristensen which row your header exist

Comment: its not technically the row or a column, if you look at the photo youll see its just there